# Проблема с установкой octobercms

Tags: php, mysql, cms, octobercms

Проблема:

При установке octobercms, во время всех этих загрузочных моментов, возникает данная ошибка:[image: Ошибка]

Вот сами логи, сам я, к сожалению, вообще ничего не знаю про php, мне нужна данная cms'ka просто для локальных проектов. Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Вот сам текстовый [файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3y4v5gKDiCKHJb2ru9CqmMwGSyPWQRu/view?usp=sharing) с логами

Comment: По логам ничего не ясно, как будто он не полный. Может лог не правильный загрузили?

Comment: Вряд ли, у меня такой файлик один :(

Comment: У вас просто идет прерывание лога на `[2021/02/19 12:48:49] Install step: setupConfig`